# Extra character from textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have two pages like this:

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="test2.php">
    <textarea id="input" name="input" cols="100px" rows="15" wrap="soft" placeholder="put input here"></textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="getLength()">Get length </button><p id="length"> </p></div>
    <br >
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function getLength(){
    var len=$('textarea').val().length;
    $('#length').text(len);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And test2.php

```
<?php
echo strlen($_POST['input']);
?>
```

When I enter some input eg: `"aa[pressEnter]aa"`, It should echo 5 at test2.php page but it echoes 6 instead.

So why it is 6 (what is extra character) ?

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Return is counted as an extra character in chrome.

Actually return is 2 escape characters \r\n. In chrome it takes one character (idk why), in edge it takes it as 2 characters so aa[enter]aa sums up to 6 characters

EDIT: 2 parts are there, one is js fix for removal of return carriage and one is php fix

**js fix in html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="test2.php">
    <textarea id="input" name="input" cols="100px" rows="15" wrap="soft" placeholder="put input here"></textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="getLength()">Get length </button><p id="length"> </p></div>
    <br >
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function getLength(){

    var fixedText = $('textarea').val();

    fixedText = fixedText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");

    var len=fixedText.length;

    $('#length').text(len);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**php fix**

```
<?php

    $data = str_replace("\r\n",'',$_POST['input']);
    echo strlen($data);

?>
```

You just need to replace the return carriages \r\n, \r and \n with "".

Comment: Hi, I tested this on Chrome and Firefox, it results the same. Can you suggest some way to get input from user without adding character.

Comment: Hi, in my code, the javascript code works well ("aa[pressEnter]aa" is 5), only when the string sent to php page then it added one charecter,  so I just need change php code like $data = str_replace("\r\n","\n",$_POST['input']) and it works.

Comment: Oh! Okay, glad you solved your issue :D Happy to help! :D